# Como fazer um gravador de tela?

Tags: c++, algoritmo

Eu estou querendo fazer um gravador de tela. O que eu pensei em fazer foi o seguinte:
A partir do evento de gravação bater 30 screenshots por segundo e depois juntá-las em sequência para formar um vídeo.
Nesse ponto que surgem algumas dúvidas:

- Essa é a maneira correta de se pensar em como fazer uma gravação da tela?
- Se sim, como eu poderia capturar uma screenshot e converter um conjunto de imagens em um vídeo?
- Se não, qual seria a forma mais correta de fazer?

Como eu disse no começo da questão, ainda está tudo no campo das ideias, ainda não tenho nenhum algoritmo e, também, não quero um programa completo, queria mais uma resposta referente as dúvidas teóricas e um direcionamento em como fazer isso em c++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bom dia,

O mais correto é capturar as informações diretamente da placa de video.

Operações de screen shot são lentas pois podem envolver até um redraw da tela inteira, e no caso de aplicativos que utilizam OpenGL ou DirectX, é provável que as surfaces aceleradas não sejam rederizadas no screen shot (antes do Windows Vista isso ocorria, hoje me parece que não ocorre mais).

Em todo o caso, esta questão do SO em inglês te da uma introdução razoável sobre como fazer:

[Fastest method of screen capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069104/fastest-method-of-screen-capturing)

Quaisquer dúvidas sobre a questão em inglês, poderei te ajudar.

Comment: Então, pelo que eu entendi, ele faz exatamente o que eu falei... Ele bate um screenshot e depois junta tudo em um vídeo. Ou eu estou equivocado? .__.

Comment: Na minha opinião não ficou claro o que o autor da questão utilizou no fim das contas. Mas eu acredito que tenha sido sim isso que ele fez. A resposta com o maior número de votos (16 no momento) nada mais faz do descrever como tirar printscreen. O interessante, pelo menos, é que com aquele código é possível tirar printscreen de uma única janela ao invés do desktop inteiro: basta utilizar o DC da janela ao invés do DC do desktop.

Comment: Boa, isso me leva a segunda pergunta, como eu faria pra "comprimir" todas as imagens e transformá-las em vídeo?

Comment: Essa é uma outra saga completamente diferente. De uma olhada na `libav`. Ela é dedicada para codificação e decodificação de áudio e video. Este exemplo deve ajudar: `https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/api-example_8c-source.html`